# How to access Locale field values through ::get() using Silverstripe Fluent

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

We are working on a project using Silverstripe with the [Fluent module](https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent) to enable multiple translations.

Here's an example Data Object with Fluent enabled. First we create the Data Object & explicitly set the CMS fields:

```
namespace Yard;

use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\TextField;

class Milkshake extends DataObject {
  private static $table_name = 'Milkshake';

  private static $db = [
    'Title' => 'Varchar(255)'
  ]

  public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = new FieldList(
        new TextField('Title', 'Milkshake Title', null, 255)
    );
    $this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields);
    return $fields;
  }
}
```

Then we set `Title` as translatable in a YML file:

```
Yard\Milkshake:
  extensions:
    - 'TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentExtension'
  translate:
    - 'Title'
```

This gives us an object with a translatable `Title` field that can have different values in different locales. It creates the following database table:

**Milkshake_Localised**

```
ID | RecordID | Locale | Title
```

So far so good, except using:

`$milkshake = Milkshake::get()->first()` doesn't return the localised data & pulls from the `Milkshake` table.

I think it could be possible to use:

```
$locale= FluentState::singleton()->getLocale();
$milkshake = Milkshake_Localised::get()->filter(['Locale' => $locale])->first();
```

But this feels clumsy & has no fallback if the locale data doesn't exist for that field (at which point it should fall back to the default locale, or failing that the original `Milkshake` field).

What is the correct way to access Locale data in Fluent so there is a fallback if required?

Comment: Are global fallback locales a possible solution for you? See https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/docs/en/scenarios.md
If that's too general, you can call the object through "withState", see https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/docs/en/state.md#mutating-state

Comment: @wmk - calling the object "withState" works. If you'd like to put that into an answer I can mark it as correct: `$milkshake = FluentState::singleton()->withState(function (FluentState $state) { return Milkshake::get()->first(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired behaviour by wrapping the get command in "[withState](https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/docs/en/state.md#mutating-state)"

```
use TractorCow\Fluent\State\FluentState; 

$milkshake = FluentState::singleton()->withState(function (FluentState $state) {
 return Milkshake::get()->first(); 
});
```